# Is there any simple and quick way to change hair path for men?

Tags: hair

In general, hair is habituated to fall in specific direction and orientation.

If we want to change its path quickly, how to achieve it without using advanced tools.

Is it possible?

Else, how to achieve it slowly? Does combing regularly is only the solution?

Answer (score 3):

According to my studies in trichology, every head has a unique pattern of hair follicles with a "grain" or direction of growth. The pattern is determined by your genetics and isn't alterable. Each hair is an extrusion of protein from each of your follicles in much the same way toothpaste is squeezed from a tube. In the case of a head-of-hair, every tube can be pointed in its own direction.

For example: A cow-lick is a circular pattern of hair growth familiar to many which can turn to the right or left and be centred on the scalp, more or less.

If you wash your hair and brush/comb it straight when wet, the pattern will be much less evident; yet, it is still there. The shaft of each hair has been temporarily *bent* into the direction you want.

"Fighting" with your hair means that you are bending/forcing your hair in a direction contrary to its natural tendency. A "good" cut uses your natural hair direction along with variable length to achieve your individuality.

Identifying each person's unique hair growth pattern is a trait of a good hair-care professional. Working with the tendency of the hair to grow in its own pattern allows some hair styles to need little or no care to maintain. A good hair cut requires the minimum of "hold."

If you can form and hold your hair in its desired shape ***as*** it is drying, you will be able to achieve the shape you wish without any additional materials, optimally for the longest time. This means that you must start with washed, wet hair and apply heat to it as you comb/brush it for the full duration that it takes to completely dry. In effect, you are heat-forming your hair. It is similar to putting wet hair into a roller and drying it in that shape. Usually, this is done with an optional starch solution to more permanently hold the style.

Answer (score 2):

You can try, after showering, to comb it in the way you want and let it dry in that way (be it with a hair dryer or naturally). If you find it starts assuming its original direction at some point when it's dry, just wet it a bit (enough to be able to shape it) and comb it again. Combining this with some sort of hair styling products will give you better results.

Answer (score 1):

Hair follicles are all "aimed" in a particular direction, and I don't think they can be changed. Only the hair that has grown out 1/2" or more can be "trained".

I override all of that by using hair products. Generally I use a strong mousse, but I have also used hair gel and hairspray. It only affects the hair I apply it to; it does not "train" my hair to grow that way, so if I don't apply product to my hair, the new hair that grows out will go in the direction the follicles are naturally pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much hair is left and the a little [pomade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomade), [hair wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_wax), and [gel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_gel) on the top of the head.  If your hairs are anyway short, already the volume of a pea may be much more than necessary to get this done to get something like

[image]

([credit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_gel))

provided you allow the clay to warm up between your fingers (a [comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNBDDDIqlMk) of the options).  The result you get by them differs from the one using a a spray.

And if «changing the hair path for men» was about the moustache, there still is [wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moustache_wax) (a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUaGKjKXY6k))